# Adding a div on clicking a button but the divs which are added are not responding same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am performing that  On Button Clicked a div is created but issue is that it is not performing as same as main div is performing like resizing & draggable.Please Help?

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
     $("#box").resizable({
    alsoResize:"#main",
    alsoResize:"#title_bar",
    alsoResize:"#container"
    });
    $('#main').draggable();
           $("#button").click(function () {
                if ($(this).html() == "-") {
                    $(this).html("+");
                    } else {
                    $(this).html("-");
                }
                $("#box").slideToggle();
            }); 
    $("#NewWidget").click(function() {

             $("#container").append('<div class="main" id="main"><div id="title_bar" ><div id="button">-</div></div><div id="box"><div><h4>Hi user</h4><p>Hello Users. How are YOU?</p> </div></div>');

     });
    });</script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <input type="button" id="NewWidget" value="Add New Widget"/>
    <div id="container">
    <div class="main" id="main"  > 
            <div id="title_bar" >
            <div id="button">-</div>
        </div>
        <div id="box">
    <div>
```

Comment: you use a lot of same ids. if you have two elements with same id on same page, jquery select only the first one. in that case you should use class selector. and another problem that may be is that when you create new div, it doesn't have any event listeners. you have to set event listener to your new div right after it's creation

Comment: Suppose i have a div & i want that on button clicked sreplica of that div is created which performs the same function as that of original div.The what can i do for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID's needs to be unique, so if you create a lot of elements, either make ID's unique or use classes or `data-id` attribute to recognize which box is which - in the example in codepen i showed you how to create ID's with simple `counter` variable, that is available in this scope (remember about closures).

What you did in your code is only `appending` a new structure to DOM, there is no event handlers/hooks attached to this element, that's why you either need to create new event handler/hooks when adding the element to the DOM, or after, in my example, i will to it before adding the element to the DOM.

Here's link to codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEyPXr

Additional hint: whenever possible, avoid creating anonymous function, always either name them, or reffer to them, meaning:

```
 $(".main").find('.button').on('click',function(){
   // this looks weak, plus anonymous function doesn't tell you what it does
});
```

use this instead:

```
$(".main").find('.button').on('click',makeButtonWork);

function makeButtonWork(){
  //this looks much better, plus you named the function and you know the purspose of it, without looking through code
}
```

To respond to comments:
changing starting position of given element can be done by adding:

`$('#main-' + counter).css({'top': 100, 'left' : 20}) //your positions here`
 in the `makeButtonWork`

see updated codepen for more info

Comment: Suppose i have a div & i want that on button clicked same new div is created which performs the same function as that of original div.The what can i do for that?

Comment: If i understood your question correctly, then the answer is on codepen i attached to this answer - take a look :). Each time you click on "Add new Widget", you're creating a new element (same as last one) which behaves the same way - because you created the behaviour from the same "definitions" (in this case - functions in Javascript)

Comment: Yaa thanks its working but what to do with its CSS?The Background colour of the divs nd if i have to work differently on every div then what can i do?

Comment: Ya we can do it with calss name.Its done .Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sir one thing i want more is that if instead of button i normally call AddWidget function & want to pass x,y,width,height of that particular div & the div sets to that exact location

Comment: I added explanation about chanign the position to the answer - please check out the codepen also

Answer (score 0):

Javascript events don't work this way. Take it as that in the moment when you call `$('#main').draggable();`, then browser finds matching element (here the one with ID 'main') and does some action with it (here enables the draggable functionality). 
If you later add another element, which would also have been matching, it doesn't mean anything - it is just a plain div, until you call some script again.

Also, keep in mind that ID's must be unique on your page, you can't have two id="main" divs on same page. Use classes instead.

```
$("#NewWidget").click(function() {
    var $newElement = $('<div class="main"><div class="title_bar" ><div class="button">-</div></div><div class="box"><div><h4>Hi user</h4><p>Hello Users. How are YOU?</p> </div></div>');
    $newElement.find('.main').draggable();
    $newElement.find('.button').click(  /* add the click handler function here */ );
    $newElement.find('.box').resizable( /* resizable params goes here */ );
    $("#container").append($newElement);
});
```

Comment: Suppose i have a div & i want that on button clicked same new div is created which performs the same function as that of original div.The what can i do for that?